# OS X AppKit executable without Info.plist

Tags: cocoa, appkit

Is it possible to create a single-executable AppKit application for OS X -- that is, without the accompanying `.app` bundle and without the `Info.plist`?

This is possible under GNUstep and is quite handy for simple examples or for quick tests, but I'd love to be able to do this under OS X as well, primarily to facilitate easier testing and comparison of behavior between these two implementations of OPENSTEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a command-line tool that links to AppKit.

Comment: Did you verify this? I'm getting "No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting". I'm compiling directly on CLI (the whole point of the exercise), but it should make no difference. This very error is the reason why I'm asking.

Comment: You need to [embed the Info.plist into the executable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW6). Searching for "embed info.plist" on SO should give you more background if you need it.

Comment: @IvanVučica: You either need to embed it, as noted by Kurt Revis, or just not use an Info.plist file (most command-line apps don't).

Comment: The question was about an "AppKit application" -- that is, a full-fledged app. They always need an Info.plist. Command-line tools are not typically referred to as "apps".

Comment: @KurtRevis: The question doesn't use the word "app". It talks about "executables" and "applications".

Comment: @mipadi: Command line tools are not commonly called "applications" nor "apps", and I explicitly mentioned AppKit. ;)

Comment: @KurtRevis: You should have posted your comment as an answer :-))